# Dropdown list moves other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

Here I have a dropdown entirely made using vanilla JavaScript.
But the thing when I click on the dropdown-btn it moves other elements.

```js
let dropdownBtn = document.querySelector("button.dropdown-btn");
let itemListWrapper = document.querySelector("div.item-list-wrapper");

dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (itemListWrapper.style.display === "none") {
    itemListWrapper.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    if (itemListWrapper.style.display === "block" || itemListWrapper.style.display === "") {
      itemListWrapper.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});

function continuouslyClickDropdownBtn() {
  dropdownBtn.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    continuouslyClickDropdownBtn();
  }, 750);
}

continuouslyClickDropdownBtn();
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.dropdown-wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 0.9);
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.75em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-list-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.dropdown-item-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.1em
}

.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-item span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 1empx;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>upper text</p>
  <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Media Quality</button>
    <div class="item-list-wrapper">
      <ul class="dropdown-item-list">
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <span>360p</span>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <span>720p</span>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-item">
          <span>1080p</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>bottom text</p>
</div>
```

I tried adding this CSS:

```css
.item-list-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  position: absolute;
}
```

But then it removes the background-color from all items.
Even if add say `background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 0.9);` to the class it just adds it to the width of items.
I can't get the background-color to wrap around the whole dropdown once it is open.

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning for `.item-list-wrapper`, adding additional rules to normalize the display of this dropdown menu. Use this selector with css rules:

```
.item-list-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.3em 0.3em;
}
```

With these rules, you inherit the background color, make the width relative to the parent, and set border-radius for the bottom of the dropdown menu.

```js
let dropdownBtn = document.querySelector("button.dropdown-btn");
let itemListWrapper = document.querySelector("div.item-list-wrapper");

dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (itemListWrapper.style.display === "none") {
        itemListWrapper.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        if (itemListWrapper.style.display === "block" || itemListWrapper.style.display === "") {
            itemListWrapper.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});

function continuouslyClickDropdownBtn() {
    dropdownBtn.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
        continuouslyClickDropdownBtn();
    }, 750);
}

continuouslyClickDropdownBtn();
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0 2em;
}

.dropdown-wrapper {
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 0.9);
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-btn {
    border-radius: 0.3em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.75em;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item-list-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.3em 0.3em;
}

.dropdown-item-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.1em;
}

.dropdown-item {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-item span {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0 1empx;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>upper text</p>
    <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
        <button class="dropdown-btn">Media Quality</button>
        <div class="item-list-wrapper">
            <ul class="dropdown-item-list">
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <span>360p</span>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <span>720p</span>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <span>1080p</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>bottom text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!. Works perfectly. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @DostArora, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have an `inner-wrapper` and set it to `position:fixed`
You'll have to set the height of the `dropdown-wrapper` so the element still has a block-presence on the page

```js
let dropdownBtn = document.querySelector("button.dropdown-btn");
let itemListWrapper = document.querySelector("div.item-list-wrapper");

dropdownBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (itemListWrapper.style.display === "none") {
    itemListWrapper.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    if (itemListWrapper.style.display === "block" || itemListWrapper.style.display === "") {
      itemListWrapper.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});

function continuouslyClickDropdownBtn() {
  dropdownBtn.click();
  setTimeout(() => {
    continuouslyClickDropdownBtn();
  }, 750);
}

continuouslyClickDropdownBtn();
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0 2em;
}

.dropdown-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: fit-content;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 0.9);
  padding: 0.3em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

.dropdown-btn {
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.75em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-list-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.dropdown-item-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.1em
}

.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.2em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-item span {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0 1empx;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>upper text</p>
  <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
      <button class="dropdown-btn">Media Quality</button>
      <div class="item-list-wrapper">
        <ul class="dropdown-item-list">
          <li class="dropdown-item">
            <span>360p</span>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item">
            <span>720p</span>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-item">
            <span>1080p</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>bottom text</p>
</div>
```